# Tigger phpmyadmin #1292 - Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ''

Tags: mysql

I've problem with PHPMYADMIN TIGGER.

```
UPDATE `products` SET `price` = '115' WHERE `products`.`id` = 1
 

#1292 - Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ''
```

This is tigger:

```
 DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER update_listing_price
    AFTER UPDATE ON products
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       IF NEW.price IS NOT NULL THEN
           UPDATE listing
           SET price = NEW.price
           WHERE listing.parent_product_id = OLD.id;
       END IF;
    END;
    //
    DELIMITER ;
```

I checed and both columns have the same structure (price and stock).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/rxvDe7mj . please add table definitions.

Comment: '115' ist a string not a value. try without quotes - 115

Comment: @Akina - sorry, the weather is not good for me :-)